# An equivalent for a Class.forName call without exception handling

Tags: java, spring, class, exception, classnotfoundexception

I was wondering if there is *"a method-wrapper"* over the method `Class.forName(className)` which throws an unchecked exception if the checked `ClassNotFoundException` happens.

My problem is to handle these types of exceptions inside a lambda body. It looks too scruffy:

```
definition -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            context.getBean(Class.forName(definition.getBeanClassName()));
            ...
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
});
```

Or do I have to write my own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring knows the `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName` method which is an equivalent for `Class.forName` but throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` if the class cannot be found.

Comment: that's a good point, but I don't know about a classloader which should be as the second param to the method

Comment: when I pass a null, it tries to use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()

Comment: Yes, you can pass null. The javadoc states:
"@param classLoader the class loader to use (may be {@code null}, which indicates the default class loader)"

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, a note on style.  If a lambda is more than one statement, you should seriously consider making it a method in its own right.  This really helps from reusability, maintainability and debuggability perspectives.

To answer your question, no, no such wrapper exists as part of core Java.  Writing your own (in a named method) shouldn't be that painful though.

Comment: thank you for the response, there are 2-3 lines only, does any 3rd party lib do it for me? I wouldn't like to write own method for the single case which leads to implementation of own exception as well

Comment: Not gonna lie, I've not looked.  Probably because any time I've come across this situation, I've decided that it would take longer than 90 seconds (the time it takes to create one in any modern IDE) to find one.

Comment: Second time in the same project?  In that case, perhaps you need a utility class.

Comment: I faced with the issue for the second time (on different projects), so looking for a way to prevent duplicate code in the future.

Comment: For reasons of decoupling, i actually would copy these 3 lines. Does not cause regressions when some other dev thinks something like: "hey an `IllegalStateException` will fit better than an `IllegalArgumentException`. I'm gonna change it without looking up all usages"